# Can't clear inputs when using Remix.js Form element

Tags: remix.run

when submitting remix form with `<Form>`element i can't clear inputs after submit. In my particular case, that form is sitting on child route within `<Outlet />` component (using nested routes here)
When form is submitted, all is working fine, redirect in handler goes to parent, parent is refreshing but child doesn't and inputs remains with values entered, that's a problem.
form is quite regular, inputs and button, all manages `action` function in parent

```
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  const formData = await request.formData()
  const data = Object.fromEntries(formData)
  await doSomething(data)
  return redirect('/route/add')
}
```

When instead of remix `<Form/>`element i use regular `<form>` element (its the only change) -  total form refresh happen - and its also working, but extra request processing, and is impossible to use tasty remix hooks, like `useTransition`

how i cut the corner

```
  const submit = useSubmit()
  function submitHandler(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault()
    // total shame
    evt.target.title.value = ''
    evt.target.body.value = ''
    submit(evt.target, {
      action: '/route/add',
      method: 'post',
    })
  }
```

so question is: how clear inputs after submitting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually more of a React question instead of a Remix one.

Remix doesn't unmount your `Outlet` on navigation.

Remix is simply fetching data from your loaders and React is then rendering. As you know, initial state and default value do not get reset on re-render. The component must unmount. The simplest way is to update the `key` prop to trigger React to remount.

Comment: thanks a lot. its working.
but another quiestion rose)) i reuse one form for creating and updating, 
with switching (or seems to be adding) form instances by key
`<Form method="post" key={item?.id ?? tmp}>`
when if edit mode - form use `item.id`, when new - use `tmp`, 
where `tmp` is kinda `Math.Random().toString()` 

Its working fine, but i suggest  multiple already used but still alive form instances may cause some memory leak. isn't it? Or GC will take care of that?

Comment: No, React is only going to have one form instance. Once a component with a key disappears, it's removed from the DOM. That's why changing the key will force React to unmount the old form and mount a new form. Same keys will reuse the same instance.